# buzz.all().mute() does not work in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, buzz.js

I am using Buzz library for my audio within an HTML5 game. To cross menus without the music stopping, I load each menu in an iframe and the music is launched from the main page:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
    <iframe id="MainFrame" src="./mainmenu.html" 
     frameborder=0 seamless="seamless" class="mainframe"></iframe>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            playLoop('audio/menumusic.mp3');
        }
</script>
</body>

var playLoop = function(name)
{
    sound = new buzz.sound(name, {preload: true, loop: true});
    sound.play();
    setInitialSoundState(sound);
    loops.add(sound);
}
```

Thing is that I want to be able to toggle/change the music in the pages loaded within the iframe. But whenever I use

```
buzz.all().mute();
```

nothing happens. I'm guessing that the `buzz` variable in the iframe and the `buzz` variable from the main page are not the same. How can I access the main page's `buzz` so that all music is muted correctly?

I'll be happy to give out more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.parent.buzz.all().mute();
// window.parent references an iframe's parent window
// or the current window if the call is made from a regular page (i.e. not in an iframe)
```

Comment: May be also `window.parent.contentWindow.buzz.all().mute();`

Comment: This works fine if you are in the same domain. Unfortunately, I am working locally, so I was getting some safety errors. Switched to postMessage() to msg the main window to stop the music.